# PHP - Get 5 unique values from array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have an array of letters and I want to pick 5 unique ones.

```
$variable_array = array('x', 'n', 'f', 'w', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'u', 'p', 'a', 'd', 'h', 'k', 'z');
```

So, I want something like this...

```
$variable_1 = $variable_array[array_rand($variable_array)];
$variable_2 = $variable_array[array_rand($variable_array)];
$variable_3 = $variable_array[array_rand($variable_array)];
$variable_4 = $variable_array[array_rand($variable_array)];
$variable_5 = $variable_array[array_rand($variable_array)];
```

but all of the variables need to be unique.   I know there are other answers similar to this on Stackoverflow already, but they all seem to be slightly different than my situation.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to select a random element from the array?

Comment: Well, each $variable_1, $variable_2, etc. needs to be unique.  So, I need 5 unique elements.

Comment: You got your solution mate. That should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP shuffle(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

```
// make sure you have only unique values in your array
// $variable_array = array_unique($variable_array);


// randomize array
shuffle($variable_array);

// get 5 elements like suggested in the comments:
// $top5_array = array_slice($variable_array, 0, 5);
$top5_array = ARRAY();

// do 5 times ...
//
// if (is_array($variable_array) AND count($variable_array) >=5) {
//
for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
  $top5_array[] = $variable_array[$i];
  print $variable_array[$i].'<br />';
}

var_dump($top5_array);
```

Comment: array_slice() woud be better than your loop

Comment: Might be, but this is just a demonstration on how to even get the 5 or one single of the wanted elements ... so not my job ;)